# subprocess FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, gsutil

I'm running python code on Ubuntu with `python3 test.py`. However got following error:

```
File
"/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geowombat/util/web.py",
line 1679, in list_gcp
        proc = subprocess.run(gsutil_str.split(' '),
      File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 489, in run
        with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
      File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
        self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
      File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
        raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gsutil'
```

It seems that subprocess imported in web.py cannot find gsutil to call.

Any idea how to solve this? I'm totally new to these, any hint helps! Thanks in advance!

---

More details:

test.py can be simplified as following:

```
from geowombat.util import GeoDownloads
path = xx
row = xx
gdl = GeoDownloads()
gdl.list_gcp('l5', f'{path:03d}/{row:03d}')
```

And I went to GeoDownloads.list_gcp() in web.py mentioned in errormsg, it's calling gsutil as `subprocess.run(['gsutil', ...])`. However, if I change test.py to following snippet it works fine:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["gsutil"])
```

Additionally, I tried adding path of gsutil (`/opt/anaconda3/bin/gsutil`) to PATH env, the error will change to "`NotADirectoryError: Not a directory: 'gsutil'`".

---

Supplement:
`/opt/anaconda3/bin` already exists in PATH env. PATH looks like this: `/opt/anaconda3/bin:/opt/anaconda3/condabin:...`

Comment: Given the last error message, can you try adding `/opt/anaconda3/bin` to your PATH?

Comment: Yes, it's already in PATH

Comment: I think @edemaine is saying to drop the "gsutil" at the end. You've added the program to the path, not its parent directory.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. The PATH is like: /opt/anaconda3/bin: ... without /opt/anaconda3/bin/gsutil. 
But if I add /opt/anaconda3/bin/gsutil to PATH, the error will change to the last errormsg.

Comment: What exactly are the contents of the `gsutil` file?  If it exists, I'm guessing it's a dangling symlink, or a script which needs an interpreter which is not found. (For example, a shebang like `#!/misspelled/bin/sh` will produce this error message on some systems.)

Comment: Thanks for replying! I have solved it temporarily. Please see answer below. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, thanks a lot to @edemaine and @tdelaney. I tried adding `/opt/anaconda3/bin` to PATH again and it seems to pass the problem and move forward. Not sure why, it seems that it can only resolve newly added PATH